# Ignore header and footer lines when reading a text file

Tags: c#

This is my code so far:

```
string _nextLine;
string[] _columns;
char[] delimiters;

delimiters = "|".ToCharArray();

using (StreamReader _reader = ...)
{
    _nextLine = _reader.ReadLine();

    while (_nextLine != null)
    {
        _columns = _nextLine.Split(delimiters);
        JazzORBuffer.AddRow();
        JazzORBuffer.Server = _columns[0];
        JazzORBuffer.Country = _columns[1];
        JazzORBuffer.QuoteNumber = _columns[2];
        _nextLine = _reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The first 5 lines of my file look as follows:

```
PRODUCTS created betwen x and y

Column 1 Header | Columns 2 Header | Column 3 Header | Column 4 Header |

Wendy Z| Dave | John | Steve |
```

The last 3 lines look as follows:

```
Wendy Z| Dave | John | Steve |

Total number of prods| 49545
```

What do I need to change in my code so the first 3 lines and the last line in the file are ignored?

Comment: could you please be explain in detail what issue are you trying to resolve

Comment: Just curious, why do some of your local variables start with _?

Comment: Trying to import a directory of 200 text files where the number of columns can vary . First 40 will be fixed and always there and the remaining 60 will vary in terms of they may be misisng from some of them. So doing a Script tranformation task in a SSIS data flow to bring all the text files into database in one go .

Comment: Just to clearly identify them ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand this question, but try:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("FilePath");
string[] _columns;

//Start at index 2 - and keep looping until index Length - 2
for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length - 2; i++)
{
    _columns = lines[i].Split('|');
    JazzORBuffer.AddRow();
    JazzORBuffer.Server = _columns[0];
    JazzORBuffer.Country = _columns[1];
    JazzORBuffer.QuoteNumber = _columns[2];
}
```

Note - this will change the performance of what you're doing, by reading the whole file into memory in one go. If it's a very large file, this may not be performant. If it is, say so :)

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but one suggestion and one limitation.  Suggestion: use the simple line `string[] columns = lines[i].Split('|');` rather than splitting the declaration and initialization.  Limitation: this only works for smallish files that can fit entirely in memory, because otherwise File.ReadAllLines will fail.  [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) could be a suitable replacement in the case of large files.

Comment: you're quite right, however, the issue with ReadLines, is that you don't know when you've reached the 2nd-to-last line - unless you do a redundant pass of the file, and count all the lines. Either way, you have a performance limitation.

Comment: I get this error trying this .        Error                       1 The name 'i' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: This methods works . But for me it stops at line 49155 for some reason . Very weird ! Can supply data as it is confidential . Doh !

Comment: @DaveBish No, you don't know whether you've reached the second-to-last line, but you don't need two passes to ignore the last line.  You can keep the most recent *two* lines in memory, and as you read the current line you process the previous line.  Once you hit the last line of the file, you are processing the second-to-last line, so you never end up processing the last line (which is the desired behavior).  This idea isn't as clean or as easy to explain as your solution, but it does allow processing of very large files.